# How does these convergences allow me to pass limit in $g \circ u^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

> Suppose $\{u^n\}$ is converging strongly in $L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R^m})$ and also it is bounded in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^m})$. Then how can we pass to the limit in $g \circ u^n$ for any continuous $g$?

I tried few things, but I believe they will probably not work, I was thinking of extracting a convergent subsequence from $\{u^n\}$ , but later on realised that it would depend on which compact we take are taking as we are in $L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R^m})$

Comment: $g$ is continuous? what about using pointwise a.e. convergence and dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the problem, but this convergence would depend upon the compact set we choose for $L^2_{loc}$, could you please elaborate